# помогите нужно решить задачу по js

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию `filterBy()`, которая будет принимать 2 аргумента. Первый аргумент – массив, который будет содержать любые данные, второй аргумент – тип данных.

- Функция должна вернуть новый массив, содержащий все данные, которые были переданы в аргумент, за исключением тех, тип которых был передан вторым аргументом. То есть, если передать массив ['hello', 'world', 23, '23', null], и вторым аргументом передать 'string', то функция вернет массив [23, null].

Результат получил, но решение не верно, логика должна быть в самой функции
Помогите пожалуйста с решением

```js
function filter_list(arr) {
    var newArr = arr.filter(x => typeof x !== "string");
    return newArr
};

function filterBy(arr, str) {
    var newArr = str(arr)
    console.log(newArr)
};

filterBy(['hello', 'world', 23, '23', null], filter_list);
```

Comment: Вячеслав, а зачем вы создали  filter_list? она же возвращает массив, который явно не может быть типом `string` да еще и захардкодили там `string` ? В чем Ваша логика? `должна вернуть` - это через `return` не через консоль.

Comment: Что-то в условии не так. может там которые НЕ совпадают по типу ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function filterBy(arr, type) {
    return arr.filter(item => typeof item !== type)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так.

```js
function filterBy(arr, mytype) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ((typeof arr[i]) !== mytype) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return result
};



console.log(filterBy(['hello', 'world', 23, '23', null], "string"))
```

Задачка с подвохом)